# What happens if an aeroplane travels in a pilot mode in a straight line with no stop?

Tags: kinematics

Ex. If a plane flew upwards straight it would reach outer space but what happens if it travels below the horizon in a straight line. Will it be traveling around the earth? How? And what about it if it flys just above the highest layer? Will it travel in the same straight line around the earth or will it travel in it's straight line without a curve?

Comment: You need to define a coordinate system so that the term "straight" has meaning. Do you mean "straight" based on a fixed point origin on Earth and parallel to latitude and longitude lines? Do you mean straight based on fixed-star coordinates?

Comment: "below the horizon in a straight line" - wouldn't that mean it is heading for a crash? Note that a plane depends on air - so no airplane will leave the atmosphere.

Comment: Of course for definition of "in a straight line" that a pilot would use it runs out of fuel and crashes.

Comment: If you ignore wind and assume the trust is the same on both sides of the plane so there was no curvature in the flight, then an auto-pilot "straight" fight would follow a great circle.  It looks curved to us but that's what a straight line looks like on a sphere.   http://www.gcmap.com/   Similarly, if you were to throw a baseball good and hard, it too would travel along a great circle, ignoring wind and any curve/spin put on the ball.   Longitude lines are great circles.  Latitude are not, except for the one on the equator.

Comment: Yes I would mean 'striaght' based on a fixed point on earth and parallel to latitude and longitude lines. My point of the question is how does centripetal force apply in this? And ignoring the facts does the object apply the same outside the atmosphere?